# How to place an array inside a select query

Tags: sql, database, vb6

I am trying to populate a gridview by placing an array inside the Select query. Every time I try this I get an error : Runtime error : 3705 "Operation not allowed when object is open". I understand why I am getting this error, but is there any alternative to place an array inside the select query. The code I am using is given below :

```
Public con1 As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim q As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim trainIds(30) As String
Public Sub con()
Set con1 = New ADODB.Connection
con1.Open ("tts123")
End Sub


Public Sub opentable(sql As String)
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open sql, con1
End Sub


Private Sub Command1_Click()
    trainIds(0) = "HM2"
    trainIds(1) = "HM2"
    trainIds(2) = "HM1"
    For i = 0 To 2
          q = "Select * from TrainTable Where TrainId ='" & trainIds(i) & "'"
          rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
          rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
          rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
          rs.Open q, con1
          If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
              Set DataGrid1.DataSource = rs
          Else
                MsgBox "No record found "
                rs.Close
           End If
     Next
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
      Set con1 = New ADODB.Connection
      con1.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =   E:\VBnewProject\TrainTimeSchedule"
con1.Open ("dsn=tts123")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using IN for your query

```
Select * from TrainTable Where TrainId IN {List of train ids to check}
```

Also look at passing parameters using SqlParameter object, your current code opens you up to SQL injection, look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx) for examples

Comment: Thanks for your input. How do I specify the list. Does it get separated by commas. is this going to be the search query : 
q = "Select * from TrainTable Where TrainId IN '" & (HM1,HM2,HM3) & "'"

Comment: Or do I have to place all the TrainIds within {} braces

Comment: It should be (list). Parenthesis, not braces.

Comment: The list can be hard coded (4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42), or it can be a query (Select ID from TrainTable Where trainIds like "HM*")

Comment: This query is showing compilation error. I don't understand why? 
"Select * from TrainTable Where TrainId IN List(" & HM1,HM2,HM3 & ")"

Comment: If HM1, HM2, & HM3 are the trainIDs, then your query should look like: "Select * from TrainTable Where TrainId IN ('HM1','HM2','HM3')"